# Variance of the minimum of two identical exponential random variables

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

> Let X and Y be two independent and identically distributed exponential
>   random variables, with mean 2. What is the variance of Z = min(X;Y) ?

E(X) = 2;
E(X) = 1/lambda, then lambda = 1/2;
V(X) = 1/(lambda^2) = 4;

The answer however is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the CDF of $Z$. We have:
\begin{align}
1-G(z)=\Pr(Z> z)=\Pr(X>z)\Pr(Y>z)=[\exp(-0.5z)]^2\implies G(z)=1-\exp(-z).
\end{align}
Thus, $Z$ is exponential with mean parameter $\lambda_Z=1$ with mean and variance:
$$
E(Z)=\lambda_Z^{-1}=1,\quad\operatorname{Var}(Z)=\lambda_Z^{-2}=1.
$$